# What are the common natural language expression for timespans and dates?

Tags: datetime, nlp

I am creating a natural language date parser for scheduling recurring events that span a few times a day to several times a month or year.

Please help me think of the common ways to express these events (bonus for additional languages than English)

Here's what I have so far:

```
twice everyday
once every week
Mondays and Thursdays
No later than 1/25
as needed every day
twice the last sun of every month
the 5th friday of every month at 8
```

**Edit**
This video was pretty helpful in thinking about natural language date patterns.

http://youtu.be/m-hdy9a4ac4

code: https://github.com/dcparker/temporals

I am still hoping to get a few other examples

**Edit 2**
Apparently the key words are:

```
Temporal Words and Phrases
Adverbs of Time
```

French
     http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/time.htm

```
une fois - once
une fois par semaine - once a week
quotidien - daily
tous les jours - every day
tous les deux jours - every other day
hebdomadaire - weekly
toutes les semaines - every week
mensuel - monthly
annuel - yearly
```

**Edit 3**
When in doubt, find a standard...

http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Natural/lib/DateTime/Format/Natural/Lang/EN.pm

Comment: Have you looked at what [iCal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) [supports](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545)?

Comment: Second Tuesday of each month from January to August each year (swim team management committee meeting; swim season May-July).

Comment: Maanantaisin tasaviikoin. Vid fullmåne. Dienstag oder jemals. Mañana.

Comment: I hadn't considered iCal. I'll check it out, thanks!